# eclipse pdt isn't reading phpdoc from code

Tags: eclipse, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt

I see that some IDE like (PHPStorm) can read phpDoc in code I mean when i do

```
/** @var SomeType $variable */
$var = $this->diffrentWayToCreateAnObject('SomeType');
```

or my best

```
/** @var SomeType $val */
foreach($item in $key => $var) {

}
```

PHPStorm knows that `$var` is an instance of class `SomeType`. This is very handy when I work using diffrent frameworks cause I don't always create an object using `new` keyword

Can I make my eclipse to read this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been told by several other Eclipse users before that PDT does recognize this usage of @var, although I myself have never actually seen it succeed.

One syntax change that might help your usage would be to use a fully qualified namespaced name for your data type:

```
/** @var \SomeType $var */
$var = ...
```

Note also that I corrected your variable name in your example.  If that example is actually your code verbatim, the variable name mismatch ($variable vs $var) would explain why the @var did not work.

I see the same two issues in your foreach() example too, "SomeType vs \SomeType" and "$val vs $var).

Comment: Given that the people who've told me their at-var usage in Eclipse did work, and they are people I trust, I have assumed that some editor settings in Eclipse determined whether or not the at-var usage works.